# Integrating PHP Like and Unlike into codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a Like and unlike button in codeigniter when clicked it adds one to the like . The button will be saved in database the mySql posts table (the posts table contains id,body,date,like,post_image) and every time the button has gets clicked it the like or unlike field is updated in the database by adding 1 to it. I have tried thinking about this but am getting confused. There is also a postlike table which contains(id, post_id,time, ipaddress).

**MODEL**: Post_model

```
 public function get_data(){
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT *
                             FROM posts 
                             ORDER BY st.id ASC");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**: Posts

```
 public function contents(){
    $this->data['get_data']= $this->post_model->get_data();
    $this->load->view('contents', $this->data, FALSE);
}

public function savelikes(){
$ipaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$post_id=$this->input->post('post_id');
$fetchlikes=$this->db->query('select likes from posts where id="'.$post_id.'"');
$result=$fetchlikes->result();
$checklikes = $this->db->query('select * from postlikes 
                                where post_id="'.$post_id.'" 
                                and ipaddress = "'.$ipaddress.'"');
$resultchecklikes = $checklikes->num_rows();

if($resultchecklikes == '0' ){
if($result[0]->likes=="" || $result[0]->likes=="NULL")
{
    $this->db->query('update posts set likes=1 where id="'.$post_id.'"');
}
else
{
    $this->db->query('update posts set likes=likes+1 where id="'.$post_id.'"');
}
$data=array('post_id'=>$post_id,'ipaddress'=>$ipaddress);
$this->db->insert('postlikes',$data);
}else{
$this->db->delete('postlikes', array('post_id'=>$post_id,
                                      'ipaddress'=>$ipaddress));
$this->db->query('update posts set likes=likes-1 where id="'.$post_id.'"');
}
$this->db->select('likes');
$this->db->from('posts');
$this->db->where('id',$post_id);
$query=$this->db->get();
$result=$query->result();
echo $result[0]->likes;
}
```

**VIEW**:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?> 
<div class=" row">
<div class="  col s12 m4 l8" id="card">
      <img src="<?php echo site_url() ?>assets/images/posts/<?php echo        $post['post_image']; ?>">
      <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red" href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'. $post['slug']); ?>"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <span class=" center card-title"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></span>
        <small class=" center post-date"> Posted on: <?php echo $post['created_at']; ?> in <strong><?php echo $post['name']; ?></strong></small><br>
<!--THIS IS THE DOT DOT DOT THAT TRUNCATES THE  POST LENGTH-->
<p>  <?php echo word_limiter($post['body'], 40) ; ?></p><br><br>
   <?php
  if(isset($get_data) && is_array($get_data) && count($get_data));$i=1;
    foreach ($get_data as $key => $data) { ?>
<p><a onclick="javascript:savelike(<?php echo $data['id'];?>);">
 <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> 
 <span id="like_<?php echo $data['id'];?>">
    <?php if($data['likes']>0){echo $data['likes'].' Likes';}else{echo 'Like';} ?>
 </span></a>
</p>    
 <?php } endif; ?>
</div>
  </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**AJAX**:

```
 function savelike(post_id){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('Posts/savelikes');?>",
            data: "Post_id="+post_id,
            success: function (response) {
             $("#like_"+post_id).html(response+" Likes");

            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: don't do it with an int field. make a relational table and store the user's id so they can't just sit there clicking like over and over again.

Comment: If i could get a sample code. I would be grateful

Comment: Personally I dont have time to write that out. Most people on this site won't just type it out either unless you post some code showing what you have tried. Then we may be able to help point you in the right direction. It's been years since I messed with the CI ORM, but you can just use a normal SQL query to handle the updates and fetching. Again, post wht you have so far or people will likely downvote this as one of those "do my work for me" posts

Comment: i have reedited the codes and added what i have tried

Comment: For starters - your ajax is sending Post_id and your code is expecting input->post('post_id') the casing is important. Secondly - it does look like you're logging in a relational table which is ok. but i question the need for a likes column on the posts table. Wouldn't that potentially cause a disconnect in the actual numbers? I would select count(1) as total from postlikes where ... and additionally, I wouldn't rely on IP address. Many places share common IP, like colleges, etc. you may want to set a unique cookie and use that instead

Answer (score 0):

For now, just starting with the begining of Like (small example) :

1. user Table
   CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `uid` int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
   `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL
   );
2. Messages Table
   CREATE TABLE   `messages` (
   `msg_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `message` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   `uid_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `like_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `created` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (uid_fk) REFERENCES users(uid)
   );
3. Messages Like Table
   CREATE TABLE `message_like` (
   `like_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `msg_id_fk` int(11),
   `uid_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (uid_fk) REFERENCES users(uid),
   FOREIGN KEY (msg_id_fk) REFERENCES messages(msg_id)
   );

Comment: I have a table already. It's the implementation that I am concerned about. Thanks